Can the "you can't play neigh card" downgrade be countered by a neigh card?
In Unstable Unicorns can the "you can't play neigh card" downgrade be countered by a neigh card?

Yes, Slowdown (the Downgrade card that says "You cannot play Neigh cards.") can be countered.
Wiki on Downgrades

Downgrade card:
Upon entering a stable a downgrade's effect is active.

versus
Wiki on Neigh

Neigh
All Neigh cards contain the card effect text "Play this card when any player tries to play a card. Stop that player's card from coming into play and send it to the discard pile instead."

So the Slowdown card doesn't come into play, doesn't enter a stable, and doesn't prevent the playing of Neigh against it.
